# Laravel 5.1 get first 100 results and apply pagination issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue with **Laravel 5.1** Eloquent. I want to get first 100 results from DB and then apply pagination.

```
$query = $r->get('page') !== null ? $r->page : 1;
$videos = Video::take(100)->paginate(25, ['*'],'page', $query)->setPath('videos');
```

This returns a full set of items.

Are there any other way that I can get a set of 100 items and apply pagination?

Comment: If I recall the limits don't work along with the paginator. You could use this as a reference, I hope it helps -> https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/length-aware-paginator :)

Comment: You could do something via IDs but it would not take in account deleted rows.

Comment: yea, works with `where` but not exactly what i need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following to get a specific number of pages:

```
Model::all()->take(100)->paginate(25);
```

And if you want to add specific queries you can do something like this:

```
Model::where('numbers', '>', 100)->paginate(25);
```

Another example:

```
Model::where('status', 1)->latest()->paginate(25);
```

Comment: unfortunately, the first solution does not work :( oh well, means that have to implement a logic with a where statement

Comment: @AndrejsGubars did the other solution work, and what was the returned error message. Always sent the error message so we can help better :)

Comment: cannot paginate an all() method unfortunately. I've implemented a where() logic to get the desired results, a bit dirty though.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run 2 queries, one to `take(100)` entries and, then, `pluck() the` id's then do a second `wherein($ids)->paginate(25);`.